# Errors when embedding Angular application into React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

### Background

We have an Angular application that is built to be embeddable into other websites, all its output JS bundles are combined into one JS file and then all a web page has to do is reference our JS file in a script tag and then add an element with our main component's selector to their body. This has worked in any other page or application we have embedded it into for the past few years.

### The Problem

We are now trying to embed the Angular application into a React application but there are multiple errors being thrown with relation to a file called `a11y.es5.js`.

The first error occurs in `a11y.es5.js` which seems to be called by our RxJs dependency:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
  at _global.<computed>.<computed> [as addEventListener) (ally.es5.js:1847:1)
  at Observable._subscribe (compiler..js:9840:16)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (pairwise.js 620)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (onErrorResumeNext.js:137:1)
  at subscribeToResult (timeoutWith.js:9:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (IntervalObservable.js:1:14)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (embed.bundle.js:181269:14)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber_.next (IfObservable.js:49:1)
  ...
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (onErrorResumeNext.js:137: 1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service.js.TranslateService.getTranslation (core.js:47:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service.js.TranslateService.retrieveTranslations (core.js:31:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service.js.TranslateService.use (core.js:4:1)
  at webpackJsonp../src/app/components/embed-main/embed-main.component.ts.EmbedMainComponent.initLang (main.ts:109:2) 
  at webpackJsonp../src/app/components/embed-main/embed-main.component.ts.EmbedMainComponent.ngOnInit (main.ts:109:2)
  at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (forms.js:6068:1)
  at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (forms.js:7595:1)
  at checkAndUpdateNode (forms.js:7538:1)
  at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (autocomplete.es5.js:212:18)
  at debugCheckDirectivesFn (autocomplete.es5.js:153:1)
  at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EmbedMainComponentt.ngfactory.js:21:5)
  at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (autocomplete.es5js:138:1)
  at checkAndupdateView (forms.js.7504:1)
  at callWithDebugContext (autocomplete.es5.js:539:1)
  at Object.debugCheckAndupdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (autocomplete.es5.js:76:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (forms.js:5272:1)
  at core.js:16520:1
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:16520:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ApplicationRef._loadComponent (core.js:16586:1)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:16474:1)
```

The second error occurs the Google Maps Javascript file which seems to be called somewhere in the `a11y.es5.js` file for some reason:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'l') : Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "l")
  at js?key=abc:199:85
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (ally.es5.js:871:17)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (ally.es5.js:631:1)
  at ally.es5.js:1295:17
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Task (ally.es5.js:904:13)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (ally.es5.js:671:1)
  at drainMicroTaskQueue (ally.es5.js:1064:1)
  at z (<anonymous>:55:81) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'l')
  at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/?key=abc:199:85
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://ourproducthost/embed.bundle.js:8809:26)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (https://ourproducthost/embed.bundle.js:8569:43)
  at https://ourproducthost/embed.bundle.js:9233:57
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Task (https://ourproducthost/embed.bundle.js:8842:31)
  at webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (https://ourproducthost/embed. bundle.js:8609:47)
  at drainMicroTaskQueue (https://ourproducthost/embed.bundle.js:9002:35)
  at z (<anonymous>:55:81)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by embedding the Angular application into the React application inside an iframe.